# runAsGroup / runAsUser / fsGroup does not set permissions on mounted volume

Tags: kubernetes

i am mounting a volume into a pod and I am using `runAsUser`, `runAsGroup` and `fsGroup` (non-0) in order to set the permissions of the mounted volume. Unfortunately it has no effect, the volume's permissions keep being set to root.
When i view the pod inside the k8s dashboard though, it displays the runAsUser / runAsGroup / fsGroup, so I am sure that part works. I also exec`d into the pod and made sure the pod was running with the correct user

I tried it with an nginx image and it works, so it might be related to my image. But what could possible the reason for this?

this is the build history of my image

```
28.06.23, 10:37
ARG RELEASE
28.06.23, 10:37
ARG LAUNCHPAD_BUILD_ARCH
28.06.23, 10:37
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.ref.name=ubuntu
28.06.23, 10:37
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.version=22.04
28.06.23, 10:37
ADD file:140fb5108b4a2861b5718ad03b4a5174bba03589ea8d4c053e6a0b282f439ff3 in /
28.06.23, 10:37
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
04.07.23, 22:33
ENV JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk
04.07.23, 22:33
ENV PATH=/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
04.07.23, 22:33
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=en_US:en LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
04.07.23, 22:36
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends tzdata curl wget ca-certificates fontconfig locales binutils && echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
04.07.23, 22:36
ENV JAVA_VERSION=jdk-17.0.7+7
04.07.23, 22:37
RUN set -eux; ARCH="$(dpkg --print-architecture)"; case "${ARCH}" in aarch64|arm64) ESUM='2ff6a4fd1fa354047c93ba8c3179967156162f27bd683aee1f6e52a480bcbe6a'; BINARY_URL='https://github.com/adoptium/temurin17-binaries/releases/download/jdk-17.0.7%2B7/OpenJDK17U-jre_aarch64_linux_hotspot_17.0.7_7.tar.gz'; ;; armhf|arm) ESUM='5b0401199c7c9163b8395ebf25195ed395fec7b7ef7158c36302420cf993825a'; BINARY_URL='https://github.com/adoptium/temurin17-binaries/releases/download/jdk-17.0.7%2B7/OpenJDK17U-jre_arm_linux_hotspot_17.0.7_7.tar.gz'; ;; ppc64el|powerpc:common64) ESUM='cc25e74c0817cd4d943bba056b256b86e0e9148bf41d7600c5ec2e1eadb2e470'; BINARY_URL='https://github.com/adoptium/temurin17-binaries/releases/download/jdk-17.0.7%2B7/OpenJDK17U-jre_ppc64le_linux_hotspot_17.0.7_7.tar.gz'; ;; s390x|s390:64-bit) ESUM='393f6348c6c0cb12699565cf23a7617fbfce973e6d47584a0920e99fbb1b1e3e'; BINARY_URL='https://github.com/adoptium/temurin17-binaries/releases/download/jdk-17.0.7%2B7/OpenJDK17U-jre_s390x_linux_hotspot_17.0.7_7.tar.gz'; ;; amd64|i386:x86-64) ESUM='bb025133b96266f6415d5084bb9b260340a813968007f1d2d14690f20bd021ca'; BINARY_URL='https://github.com/adoptium/temurin17-binaries/releases/download/jdk-17.0.7%2B7/OpenJDK17U-jre_x64_linux_hotspot_17.0.7_7.tar.gz'; ;; *) echo "Unsupported arch: ${ARCH}"; exit 1; ;; esac; wget -O /tmp/openjdk.tar.gz ${BINARY_URL}; echo "${ESUM} */tmp/openjdk.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c -; mkdir -p "$JAVA_HOME"; tar --extract --file /tmp/openjdk.tar.gz --directory "$JAVA_HOME" --strip-components 1 --no-same-owner ; rm -f /tmp/openjdk.tar.gz ${JAVA_HOME}/src.zip; find "$JAVA_HOME/lib" -name '*.so' -exec dirname '{}' ';' | sort -u > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/docker-openjdk.conf; ldconfig; java -Xshare:dump;
04.07.23, 22:37
RUN echo Verifying install ... && fileEncoding="$(echo 'System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"))' | jshell -s -)"; [ "$fileEncoding" = 'UTF-8' ]; rm -rf ~/.java && echo java --version && java --version && echo Complete.
10.07.23, 13:30
ARG UID=999
10.07.23, 13:30
ARG GID=999
10.07.23, 13:30
ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Xms100m -Xmx750m
10.07.23, 13:30
RUN |2 UID=999 GID=999 RUN groupadd --gid $GID spring && useradd -r -m -d /opt/spring -s /sbin/nologin --gid $GID --uid $UID -c "Spring user" spring && chmod 755 /opt/spring && apt-get update && ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin /etc/localtime && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata # buildkit
10.07.23, 13:30
WORKDIR /opt/spring
10.07.23, 13:30
USER 999
10.07.23, 13:30
EXPOSE map[8080/tcp:{}]
10.07.23, 13:30
CMD ["java" "-jar" "application.jar" "--server.port=8080" "--server.forward-headers-strategy=FRAMEWORK"]
10.07.23, 13:30
ARG GIT_COMMIT
10.07.23, 13:30
ARG BUILD_TIME
10.07.23, 14:54
WORKDIR /opt/spring
20.07.23, 17:40
COPY my-batchapplication.jar /opt/spring/my-batchapplication.jar # buildkit
20.07.23, 17:40
USER root
20.07.23, 17:40
RUN RUN mkdir /log && chown -R spring:spring /log # buildkit
20.07.23, 17:40
USER spring
20.07.23, 17:40
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
20.07.23, 17:40
ENTRYPOINT ["java" "-jar" "my-batchapplication.jar"]
```

Does anybody have an idea? I used a `linstor` volume in case that has any relevance.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include your Pod spec, and anything else needed to make a [mcve]?  The original source code will be much better than log output.  How are you configuring `fsGroup` and why do you think it doesn't have an effect?